# Changing size of login pictures on Windows7 via authui.dll

Tags: windows-7, boot

Using resource Hacker and authui.dll there is a lot of documentation about how to change various parts of the W7 login screen.

What I have so far failed to manage is to change the size of the user icons used to identify each account on the login screen....I can hide them completely, but not make them slightly larger

Any ideas?

Comment: So what happens? Do larger images get truncated, or does Resource Hacker refuse to insert them to the dll? Or is it something else?

Comment: I think issue is /where/ to add them. I have found an image in the dll that seems to represent the grey frame that borders the account picture. Resizing this and reinserting back into dll causes the dll not to load at all...so its exact dimensions are likely referenced somewhere else in the file